# Mockito and nested method call

Tags: java, mockito

I have 3 classes:

```
public class SomeDAO {

   // that method I'd want to catch and change
   public void getObj() { ... }

}

public class MainService {

    private Service2 service2;

    public void doMain() {
        service2.doSomethingAnother();
    }

}

public class Service2 {

    private SomeDAO someDAO

    public void doSomethingAnother() {
        someDAO.getObj();
    }
}
```

All I need - to call *doMain* but with custom *someDao.getObj()* inside *service2.doSomethingAnother()*:

```
public TestClass {

    @InjectMocks
    private final MainService mainService = new MainService();

    @InjectMocks
    private final Service2 service2 = new Service2();

    @Mock
    private SomeDAO someDao;

    @Test
    public void testMe() {

        // substitution
        when(someDao.getObj()).thenReturn(new MyObj());

        // then I'm calling the outer method
        mainService.doMain();

    }

}
```

When running that test I have NPE in **mainService.doMain()**: service2 in null..

Inside of **testMe** object *service2* is alive and not null, it has been declared as class variable and initialized.

Whether I misundersood @InjectMock behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Service2` is not injected into `MainService`, since it is not a mock. Therefore, the `server2` attribute of your `mainService` object is `null`.

You are also trying to mock too deep. The correct way to test `MainService` is to mock the dependency of `Service2` and not `SomeDAO`.

A separate test class for `Service2` is better where you mock the dependency of `SomeDAO`.

```
public TestClass {

    @InjectMocks
    private MainService mainService;

    @Mock
    private Service2 service2;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMe() {
        mainService.doMain();

        verify(service2).doSomethingAnother();

    }

}
```